# How to manage AngularJS workflow with lots of script files

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I looked into gruntjs but I'm not sure if it the right tool to solve my workflow problem. I' working on a huge angular project with 30+ js files already into it. Every time I add a new js file, I have to go to index file and add reference in it. Is there any way to automate this process with grunt or any other tool?

Comment: You will want to take a look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: Actually, RequireJS is somewhat tricky to get to work with AngularJS, so I don't recommend this approach. A nice Grunt-based build system seems to hit the sweet spot.

Comment: RequireJS works fine with AngularJS, but you still have to manage the requires in code (not too much better than including them in the HTML). We combine RequireJS with a node.js build process that scans directories and builds a list of required files dynamically.

Comment: I think a related has been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073111/front-end-development-workflow-with-angularjs-and-gruntjs/ , the answer given may help you here too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely! Here are two ways:

**[Yeoman](http://yeoman.io)**

Yeoman is a set of integrated workflow management scripts built on Grunt and Bower that supports automatic scaffolding and compilation. There is an [AngularJS generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) for it too.

**[ngBoilerplate](http://joshdmiller.github.com/ng-boilerplate)**

This is my creation, so I definitely have a bias here, but it has a Grunt-based built system and a defined directory structure that makes managing non-trivial AngularJS apps super easy.

Comment: Thanks Josh . Yeoman still don't have windows support. I did see your your ngBoilerplate. I'm wondering if I can adapt it according to my project structure or does it have to be according to your predefined directory structure? Also, is there any good resource to learn gruntjs? I know basic grunt task such as concat, min etc but having hard time understanding custom task(one like my question for example).

Comment: @SamSerious It's meant to work out of the box with that directory structure, but it can be adapted to any structure - Grunt is super-flexible and I defined *all* paths in variables that you can easily change (see the `src` config). Take a look at `Gruntfile.js` - it's got a *ton* of comments to help people make sense of it. As for learning Grunt, it's best to check out a few examples, figure out what they do, and read through the [wiki](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki). Grunt 0.4 was released a few weeks ago (radical changes!), so there aren't any good tutorials yet.