# Silex + Angular JS 2 Project Structure

Tags: php, angularjs, silex

I have built a small app using Angular 2 which works fine with REST APIs. However, now I would like to include the backend and the frontend in in a single project.

Presently, I am looking at [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org) and want to build an app which has Angular 2 as the front-end and Silex as the backend providing the APIs.

In my Angular js app, I have 3 different tabs, which communicate with 3 different services. I have my Angular app organized as follows:

```
Dashboard app
|
+---app
|    |
|     +--components
|     |        |
|     |        \-comp1
|     |           \-html
|     |            \-js
|     |            \-css
|     +--config
|     +--mock
|     +--services
+---package.json
+---index.html
+---node_modules
```

I am just confused on how to organize the project structure which will include both angular 2 and Silex.

Answer (score 5):

**Should you bundle them together or keep separate?**

Angular 2 and Silex are 2 separate components, and, I think you keep them as 2 separate projects, if obviously you don't have very strong reason.
I am suggesting to keep them separate because:

- The Angular App may be an SPA
- Angular App will fetch data from backend services, and it does not matter if the back-end is PHP, Rails or NodeJs

People may argue over pros and cons of keeping backend and front end separate or vice-versa, however, it's really up to you.
There are some good articles on this, that you may want to have a look to help you decide:

- [The case for separating front- and back-end](http://dontpanic.42.nl/2014/10/the-case-for-separating-front-and-back.html)
- [Let's keep frontend outside of Ruby](http://twin.github.io/lets-keep-frontend-outside-of-ruby/)
- [Separating Angularjs and Rails apps as standalone components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164068/separating-angularjs-and-rails-apps-as-standalone-components)

**Keeping them together**

If you want to together, you can either follow the structure used by Yeoman Mean generator or may be node js MVC framework.
Idea here is to have 2 separate code areas:

- Publicly accessible front end
- Restricted backend

If you have used worked on Cake or any similar framework, you'll notice they have this kind of structure. **public/** is the directory that is exposed publicly, rest everything is outside the public area.

Taking some leads from cake or mean js projects, you can create following structure:

```
index.php
src/              Your PHP App outside publically accessible public directory 
  classes/

public/             --> all of the files to be used in on the client side | Your Angular App Structure
  css/              --> css files
    app.css         --> default stylesheet
  img/              --> image files
  app/               --> javascript files
    app.js          --> declare top-level app module
    user/
      users.controller.js
      users.service.js
      users.html
    group/
      groups.controller.js
      groups.services.js
      groups.specs.js
      groups.html
    core/
      services/
        network/
          network.service.js
        db/
          databvase.service.js
        http/
          http.service.js
      services.export.js        
      components/
          directives.js   --> custom angular directives
          filters.js      --> custom angular filters

    lib/            --> angular and 3rd party JavaScript libraries
      angular/
        angular.js            --> the latest angular js
        angular.min.js        --> the latest minified angular js
        angular-*.js          --> angular add-on modules
        version.txt           --> version number
```

I follow **folder-by-feature** structure for my Angular Apps, and this really helps you organize your app in more manageable hierarchy, have a look at [John Papa - Angular App Structuring Guidelines](http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-app-structuring-guidelines/)

Hope this helps :)